# String Resource is int?

Tags: android, string, int

Eclipse tells me that my string is an int?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Uri.parse(R.string.get_question_url));
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity httpentity = new response.getEntity();
InputStream isr = httpentity.getContent();
```

Line 2: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Uri.parse(R.string.get_question_url));`
I wonder why, does anyone know help?

Comment: can u tell me what is value of R.string.get_question_url

Answer (score 2):

R.string.something returns an integer identifier of the resource, not the actual string content you seem to be expecting. You will have to use `getString()` in order to get the actual string resource from its identifier.

Use this instead for actually building the Uri from the string resource, and not from the identifier of the string resource:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.get_question_url)));
```

Assuming you run this code in a subclass of Context.

Otherwise, use:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Uri.parse(yourContext.getResources().getString(R.string.get_question_url)));
```

Answer (score 1):

All your resources in your project are identified by an `int` number, no matters what they are: Drawables, Layouts, Strings... So each time you name a resource as `android:id="@+id/whatever"`, Android internally is representing it as an `int` which you can access through the `R.resource.name` autogenerated index.